# Error: Too few points to calculate an ellipse with 3 points? - R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pca, ellipse

G'day.
I am plotting a `pca` with the `factoextra` package. I have 3 points for each factor and would like to draw ellipses around each. But I am getting the error `Too few points to calculate an ellipse`.

It is possible to draw ellipses around 3 points in `ggplot2` with the `stat_ellipse` function. I can confirm this by looking at the `calculate_ellipse` [code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ellipse.R) from `ggplot2` that says `else if (dfd < 3) {message("Too few points to calculate an ellipse")`. So what ellipse function is `factoextra` using in `fviz_pca_ind` that it considers 3 points too few? Is there a way I can force it to add ellipses? This package has specific features I need so would like to stick with it. Thanks.

```
library(factoextra)

data(iris)

iris2<-iris[c(1:3,51:53,101:103),] # 3 points for each factor

res.pca <- prcomp(iris2[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, label='none',alpha.ind = 1,
             habillage=iris2$Species,
             repel = TRUE, 
             addEllipses = TRUE,invisible='quali')+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')+
  coord_equal()

#Too few points to calculate an ellipse
#Too few points to calculate an ellipse
#Too few points to calculate an ellipse
```

[image]

Comment: You're trying to calculate an *uncertainty* ellipse in 2-parameter space. An ellipse is *uniquely* characterised by three different points, with no uncertainty. You therefore need `>3` points to be able to show an uncertainty ellipse; in other words an *uncertainty* ellipse with 3 points is a contradiction.

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks for the comment. Can you please elaborate? Do you mean this does not calculate confidence interval ellipses?

Comment: Imagine fitting a straight line through 2 points. In that case it doesn't make sense to talk about an uncertainty of the fit parameters. There is no uncertainty, because there is a unique line passing through 2 points.

Comment: Perhaps also of interest: [Real meaning of confidence ellipse](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217374/real-meaning-of-confidence-ellipse).

Comment: @MauritsEvers very intersting, thanks. I guess I am still confused as to why it is possible to draw ellipses with 3 points in `ggplot2` but not `factoextra`.

Comment: You can draw an ellipse with 3 points; but you need `>3` points to draw a *confidence* ellipse. If still unclear I can try to elaborate in an answer; won't be able to get to this for a few hours though.

Answer (score 8):

I've faced the same problem. The solution is to use `geom_mark_ellipse` from [`ggforce`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com) package. It's possible to create an ellipse around 3 points (even around 1 point).

So, the workflow should be as follows:

```
library(factoextra)
library(ggforce)

data(iris)

iris2<-iris[c(1:3,51:53,101:103),] # 3 points for each factor

res.pca <- prcomp(iris2[, -5],  scale = TRUE)

fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, label='none',alpha.ind = 1,
             habillage=iris2$Species,
             repel = TRUE, 
             # Don't use default Ellipses!!!!
             # addEllipses = TRUE,
             invisible='quali') +
  # ADD ggforce's ellipses
  ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = Groups,
                        color = Groups)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]